# COleDateTime alternative for linux

Tags: c++, linux, mfc

Good Day.

I have to make a C++ project Linux compatible. In the existing Project some old MFC functions were used. I am searching for a substitute for the COleDateTime wrapper. Does a alternative object exist for Linux or do I have to implement my own wrapper? (examples would be appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost DateTime library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time.html

Using Boost, you can make many other things portable: file system, multithreading, interprocess communications, sockets etc.

More about Boost Datetime here: http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/ Chapter 10: Date and Time